# Do we need to dispose azure powershell commands?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

We have over 400 app services and we are creating a deployment tool to deploy to all of these instances as soon as possible.

We have 4 projects running in separate app service and each customer need to have all 4 projects up and running so we have distributed the instances by customer name and each instance deploy to 4 app services internally (See the code snippet below)

We've created a powershell function app with queue trigger that is calling azure powershell commands to do the deployment. The deployment steps are:

1. Create deployment slot
2. Publish to the deployment slot
3. Version check (Have an endpoint in all projects which returns assembly version)
4. Swap slot
5. Version check again
6. Delete slot

The steps are straight forward but when I deploy to single instance it runs pretty quickly but when I am trying to deploy to multiple instances (5+) then it starts becoming really slow and eventually stops execution. My assumption is that there is a memory issue. I am using premium (EP1) plan for my function so it shouldn't be that slow.

I am totally new to powershell so the question is do I need to dispose the azure powershell stuff? Or anything else to freed the memory. If yes, how can I call dispose to azure powershell commands?

**Update**

Adding the code snippets.

Some more context:

So the run.ps1 file has the code that downloads the ps1 script file from blob storage and dynamically executes it:

**run.ps1**

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($QueueItem, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write out the queue message and insertion time to the information log.
Write-Host "PowerShell queue trigger function processed work item: $QueueItem"
Write-Host "Queue item insertion time: $($TriggerMetadata.InsertionTime)"

$currentContext = Get-AzContext -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Name -contains 'Subscriptionname'}
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroup>" -Name "<ResourceName>" -DefaultProfile $currentContext
$Context = $storageAccount.Context
    
$queue = Get-AzStorageQueue -Name logs -Context $Context

function Log {
  param (
    [string]$message, [string]$isDetailed, [string]$hasError = "false"
  )

  $jsonMessge = @"
{
  "InstanceId": "$instanceId",
  "TaskId": "$taskId",
  "Note": "$message",
  "IsDetailed": $isDetailed,
  "HasError": $hasError
}
"@
  # Create a new message using a constructor of the CloudQueueMessage class
  $queueMessage = [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueueMessage]::new($jsonMessge)

  # # Add a new message to the queue
  $queue.CloudQueue.AddMessageAsync($queueMessage)
}


try {
  #Extracting data from Queue message
  $queueMessage = $QueueItem

  $instanceId = $queueMessage.instanceId
  $taskId = $queueMessage.taskId
  $siteName = $queueMessage.siteName
  $buildNo = $queueMessage.buildNo
  $pass = $queueMessage.password
  $dbPassword = convertto-securestring "$pass" -asplaintext -force
  $servicePlanName = $queueMessage.servicePlanName
  $subscription = $queueMessage.subscription
  $key = $queueMessage.key
  $rg = $queueMessage.resourceGroup
  $sqlServerName = $queueMessage.sqlServerName

  Log -message "Deployment started for $($siteName)" -isDetailed "false"
   $tempFolder = $env:temp
  # $artifactFolderPath = "$($tempFolder)\$($siteName)\$($buildNo)"
  #$artifactFilePath = "$($tempFolder)\$($siteName)\$($buildNo).zip"
  $tempDownloadPath = "$($tempFolder)\$($siteName)"
  $scriptFileName = "DeployScripts.ps1"

  if (Test-Path $tempDownloadPath) {
    Remove-Item $tempDownloadPath -Force -Recurse
  }


  $storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "KineticNorthEurope" -Name "KineticDeployment" -DefaultProfile $currentContext

  New-Item -Path $tempFolder -Name $siteName -ItemType "directory"
  $Context = $storageAccount.Context
  $blobContent = @{
    Blob        = "DeployScripts.ps1"
    Container   = 'builds'
    Destination = "$($tempDownloadPath)\$($scriptFileName)"
    Context     = $Context
  }
  Get-AzStorageBlobContent @blobContent -DefaultProfile $currentContext

  #[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($artifactFilePath, $artifactFolderPath)

  $arguments = "-rg $rg -site $siteName -buildNo $buildNo -dbPassword `$dbPassword -instanceId $instanceId -taskId $taskId -sqlServerName $sqlServerName -subscription $subscription"

  $path = "$($tempDownloadPath)\$($scriptFileName)"
  Unblock-File -Path $path
  "$path $ScriptFilePath $arguments" | Invoke-Expression

  if (Test-Path $tempDownloadPath) {
    Remove-Item $tempDownloadPath -Force -Recurse
  }
  Log -message "Resources cleaned up" -isDetailed "false"
}
catch {
  Log -message $_.Exception.message -isDetailed "false" -hasError "true"
  if (Test-Path $tempDownloadPath) {
    Remove-Item $tempDownloadPath -Force -Recurse
  }
}
```

And here is the actual **DeployScripts.ps1** file:

```
param($rg, $site, $buildNo, [SecureString] $dbPassword, $instanceId, $taskId, $sqlServerName, $subscription)
$siteNameWeb = "${site}"
$siteNamePortal = "${site}Portal"
$siteNamePortalService = "${site}PortalService"
$siteNameSyncService = "${site}SyncService"

$kineticNorthContext = Get-AzContext -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Name -contains 'SubscriptionName'}
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroup>" -Name "<ResourceName>" -DefaultProfile $kineticNorthContext
$Context = $storageAccount.Context
    
$queue = Get-AzStorageQueue -Name logs -Context $Context
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $subscription

Function CreateDeploymentSlots() {
    Log -message "Creating deployment slots" -isDetailed "false"

    Log -message "Creating deployment slot for web" -isDetailed "true"
    New-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -name $siteNameWeb -slot develop 

    Log -message "Creating deployment slot for portal" -isDetailed "true"
    New-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -name $siteNamePortal -slot develop 
    
    Log -message "Creating deployment slot for portal service" -isDetailed "true"
    New-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -name $siteNamePortalService -slot develop 
    
    Log -message "Creating deployment slot for sync service" -isDetailed "true"
    New-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -name $siteNameSyncService -slot develop 

    Log -message "Deployment slots created" -isDetailed "false"
}

Function DeleteDeploymentSlots() {
    Log -message "Deleting deployment slots" -isDetailed "false"

    Log -message "Deleting slot web" -isDetailed "true"
    Remove-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNameWeb -Slot "develop" 
    
    Log -message "Deleting slot portal" -isDetailed "true"
    Remove-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNamePortal -Slot "develop" 
    
    Log -message "Deleting slot portal service" -isDetailed "true"
    Remove-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNamePortalService -Slot "develop" 
    
    Log -message "Deleting slot sync service" -isDetailed "true"
    Remove-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNameSyncService -Slot "develop" 

    Log -message "Slots deployment deleted" -isDetailed "false"
}

Function SwapDeploymentSlots {
    Log -message "Switching deployment slots" -isDetailed "false"

    Log -message "Switch slot web" -isDetailed "true"
    Switch-AzWebAppSlot -SourceSlotName "develop" -DestinationSlotName "production" -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNameWeb 
    
    Log -message "Switch slot portal" -isDetailed "true"
    Switch-AzWebAppSlot -SourceSlotName "develop" -DestinationSlotName "production" -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNamePortal 
    
    Log -message "Switch slot portal service" -isDetailed "true"
    Switch-AzWebAppSlot -SourceSlotName "develop" -DestinationSlotName "production" -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNamePortalService 
    
    Log -message "Switch slot sync service" -isDetailed "true"
    Switch-AzWebAppSlot -SourceSlotName "develop" -DestinationSlotName "production" -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNameSyncService 
    
    Log -message "Deployment slots switched" -isDetailed "false"
}

function Log {
    param (
        [string]$message, [string]$isDetailed, [string]$isDeployed = "false", [string]$hasError = "false"
    )
    $jsonMessge = @"
{
    "InstanceId": "$instanceId",
    "TaskId": "$taskId",
    "Note": "$message",
    "IsDetailed": $isDetailed,
    "IsDeployed": $isDeployed,
    "HasError": $hasError
}
"@
    # Create a new message using a constructor of the CloudQueueMessage class
    $queueMessage = [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueueMessage]::new($jsonMessge)

    # # Add a new message to the queue
    $queue.CloudQueue.AddMessageAsync($queueMessage)
}
function VersionCheckWeb() {
    $tls = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://${site}.net/Home/Info" -UseBasicParsing
    $content = $tls.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    $versionCheck = $content.VersionNo -eq $buildNo
    return $versionCheck
}
function VersionCheckPortal() {
    $tls = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://${site}portal.net/Home/Info" -UseBasicParsing
    $content = $tls.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    $versionCheck = $content.VersionNo -eq $buildNo
    return $versionCheck
}
function VersionCheckPortalService() {
    $tls = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://${site}portalservice.net/Home/Info" -UseBasicParsing
    $content = $tls.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    $versionCheck = $content.VersionNo -eq $buildNo
    return $versionCheck
}
function VersionCheckSyncService() {
    $tls = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://${site}syncservice.net/SyncService.svc/Info" -UseBasicParsing
    $tls = $tls -replace '[?]', ""
    $content = "$tls" | ConvertFrom-Json
    $versionCheck = $content.VersionNo -eq $buildNo
    return $versionCheck
}

function VersionCheck() {
    $versionCheckWeb = VersionCheckWeb
    $versionCheckPortal = VersionCheckPortal
    $versionCheckPortalService = VersionCheckPortalService
    $versionCheckSyncService = VersionCheckSyncService
    
    if (($versionCheckWeb -eq "True") -and ($versionCheckPortal -eq "True") -and ($versionCheckPortalService -eq "True") -and ($versionCheckSyncService -eq "True")) {
        Log -message "Version correct" -isDetailed "false"
    }
    else {
        Log -message "Version check failed, exception not thrown" -isDetailed "false"
    }
}

function VersionCheckWebSlot() {
    $tls = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://${site}-develop.azurewebsites.net/Home/Info" -UseBasicParsing
    $content = $tls.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    $versionCheck = $content.VersionNo -eq $buildNo
    return $versionCheck
}
function VersionCheckPortalSlot() {
    $tls = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://${site}portal-develop.azurewebsites.net/Home/Info" -UseBasicParsing
    $content = $tls.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    $versionCheck = $content.VersionNo -eq $buildNo
    return $versionCheck
}
function VersionCheckPortalServiceSlot() {
    $tls = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://${site}portalservice-develop.azurewebsites.net/Home/Info" -UseBasicParsing
    $content = $tls.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    $versionCheck = $content.VersionNo -eq $buildNo
    return $versionCheck
}
function VersionCheckSyncServiceSlot() {
    $tls = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://${site}syncservice-develop.azurewebsites.net/SyncService.svc/Info" -UseBasicParsing
    $tls = $tls -replace '[?]', ""
    $content = "$tls" | ConvertFrom-Json
    $versionCheck = $content.VersionNo -eq $buildNo
    return $versionCheck
}

function VersionCheckSlot() {
    $versionCheckWeb = VersionCheckWebSlot
    $versionCheckPortal = VersionCheckPortalSlot
    $versionCheckPortalService = VersionCheckPortalServiceSlot
    $versionCheckSyncService = VersionCheckSyncServiceSlot
    
    if (($versionCheckWeb -eq "True") -and ($versionCheckPortal -eq "True") -and ($versionCheckPortalService -eq "True") -and ($versionCheckSyncService -eq "True")) {
        Log -message "Slot version correct" -isDetailed "false"
    }
    else {
        Log -message "Slot version check failed, exception not thrown" -isDetailed "false"
    }
}

function PublishToAzure() {

    $webPublishProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNameWeb 
    $webXml = $webPublishProfile -as [Xml]
    $webUserName = $webXml.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
    $webUserPwd = $webXml.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
    $webpair = "$($webUserName):$($webUserPwd)"

    $webencodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($webpair))

    $webauthHeader = "Basic $webencodedCreds"
    $webHeaders = @{
        Authorization = $webauthHeader
    }


    $portalPublishProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNamePortal 
    $portalXml = $portalPublishProfile -as [Xml]
    $portalUserName = $portalXml.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
    $portalUserPwd = $portalXml.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
    $portalpair = "$($portalUserName):$($portalUserPwd)"

    $portalencodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($portalpair))

    $portalauthHeader = "Basic $portalencodedCreds"
    $portalHeaders = @{
        Authorization = $portalauthHeader
    }

    
    $portalServicePublishProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNamePortalService 
    $portalServiceXml = $portalServicePublishProfile -as [Xml]
    $portalServiceUserName = $portalServiceXml.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
    $portalServiceUserPwd = $portalServiceXml.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
    $portalServicepair = "$($portalServiceUserName):$($portalServiceUserPwd)"

    $portalServiceencodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($portalServicepair))

    $portalServiceauthHeader = "Basic $portalServiceencodedCreds"
    $portalServiceHeaders = @{
        Authorization = $portalServiceauthHeader
    }

    
    $syncServicePublishProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $siteNameSyncService 
    $syncServiceXml = $syncServicePublishProfile -as [Xml]
    $syncServiceUserName = $syncServiceXml.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
    $syncServiceUserPwd = $syncServiceXml.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
    $syncServicepair = "$($syncServiceUserName):$($syncServiceUserPwd)"

    $syncServiceencodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($syncServicepair))

    $syncServiceauthHeader = "Basic $syncServiceencodedCreds"
    $syncServiceHeaders = @{
        Authorization = $syncServiceauthHeader
    }


    $bodyWeb = '{"packageUri": "<blobUrl>"}'
    $bodyPortal = '{"packageUri": "blobUrl"}'
    $bodyPortalService = '{"packageUri": "blobUrl"}'
    $bodySyncService = '{"packageUri": "blobUrl"}'
    

    $web = Invoke-RestMethod -URI "https://${siteNameWeb}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/publish?type=zip" -Method POST -Body $bodyWeb -Headers $webHeaders -ContentType "application/json"
    Log -message "Published to Web" -isDetailed "false"

    $portal = Invoke-RestMethod -URI "https://${siteNamePortal}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/publish?type=zip" -Method POST -Body $bodyPortal -Headers $portalHeaders -ContentType "application/json"
    Log -message "Published to Portal" -isDetailed "false"

    $portalService = Invoke-RestMethod -URI "https://${siteNamePortalService}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/publish?type=zip" -Method POST -Body $bodyPortalService -Headers $portalServiceHeaders -ContentType "application/json"
    Log -message "Published to PortalService" -isDetailed "false"

    $syncService = Invoke-RestMethod -URI "https://${siteNameSyncService}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/publish?type=zip" -Method POST -Body $bodySyncService -Headers $syncServiceHeaders -ContentType "application/json"
    Log -message "Published to SyncService" -isDetailed "false"
}


try {
    CreateDeploymentSlots
    PublishToAzure
    VersionCheckSlot
    SwapDeploymentSlots
    VersionCheck
    DeleteDeploymentSlots
    Log -message "Instance deployed successfully" -isDetailed "false" -isDeployed "true"
}
catch {
    Log -message $_.Exception.message -isDetailed "false" -hasError "true"
}
```

I know the code is little mess right now and that's because I've changed the implementation to faster the process but no major luck.

**Question2**

I actually have another question as well. We've multiple subscriptions and appservices are distributed accordingly. So when function app tries to deploy to a instance exists in another subscription, it throws error. I'm setting AzContext before starting the processing and it seems to be working fine. But i also have to put message into a queue after each step and the queue exists in a storage account that belongs to same subscription as of the function app. Currently i'm getting the AzContent and passing it as -DefaultProfile while getting the storage account. Is there a better way to handle this?

Also I am writing powershell for the first time so any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you share the code snippet information so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT, I've updated my question and added code snippets and updated the description as well to make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: @Todd, could you please elaborate it little more?

Comment: Regardless of anything else, you can run things like your 4 calls to ```New-AzWebAppSlot``` and ```Remove-AppSlot``` in parallel with a ```ForEach-Object -Parallel``` or ```Start-Job``` to get better performance…

Comment: Yes,  but I think the major issue right now is either scalability or memory

Comment: Executing a powershell script is going to start up a new powershell.exe representing a single session. After the process is complete it *should* close the program and resources will be deallocated. If you're running them all in parallel, you'd need a non-trivial amount of memory to have 400 spinning up at once. Could you use more machines to execute for scaling?

Comment: For your second question, what's the error?